# How to allow one property only if other is not present and allow any of other propeties in json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have six properties: name, age, phone, deletePhone, address, deleteAddress.

I want to create schema that allows anyOf above properties but phone should not be present with deletePhone and address should not be present with deleteAddress(and vice versa).

I have tried this schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "age": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "phone": {
        "type": "number"
      },
      "deletePhone": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "address": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "deleteAddress": {
        "type": "boolean"
      }
    },
    "allOf": [
      {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "required": ["phone"]
          },
          {
            "required": ["deletePhone"]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "oneOf": [
          {
            "required": ["address"]
          },
          {
            "required": ["deleteAddress"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

It validates true

```
{
    "name": "my name",
    "address": "some addr",
    "phone": 34
}
```

and validates false for

```
{
    "address": "some addr",
    "phone": 34,
    "deletePhone": true
}
```

which is correct but it also validates false for

```
{
    "phone": 34
}
or
{
    "name": "some name"
}
```

Which i want to validate true, i know i'm missing some combination of anyOf, oneOf, Or is there any better way?

Comment: If you have access to an implementation which supports the latest draft (draft-7), you may want to look at the `if` `then` `else` keywords in the spec. if not, there's still a way, but it's more contrived. Sorry I can't write an answer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the simplest solution.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": { "type": "string" },
    "age": { "type": "number" },
    "phone": { "type": "number" },
    "deletePhone": { "type": "boolean" },
    "address": { "type": "string" },
    "deleteAddress": { "type": "boolean" }
  },
  "allOf": [
    { "not": { "required": ["phone", "deletePhone"] } },
    { "not": { "required": ["address", "deleteAddress"] } }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Just missing `"additionalProperties": false`.

Comment: Not missing, deliberately left out. One day I'll have to write an "additionalProperties considered harmful" blog post.

Comment: nice solution, however, it would be better to support this natively so that the error message tells some specific error for this case, something like "there should be either phone or deletePhone"

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** A different but more reliable and compact approach.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "age": {"type": "number"},
    "phone": {"type": "number"},
    "deletePhone": {"type": "boolean"},
    "address": {"type": "string"},
    "deleteAddress": {"type": "boolean"}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"required": ["phone"]},
            {"not":{"required":["deletePhone"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"required": ["deletePhone"]},
            {"not":{"required":["phone"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"not":{"required": ["deletePhone"]}},
            {"not":{"required":["phone"]}}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"required": ["address"]},
            {"not":{"required":["deleteAddress"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"required": ["deleteAddress"]},
            {"not":{"required":["address"]}}
          ]
        },
        {
          "allOf": [
            {"not":{"required": ["deleteAddress"]}},
            {"not":{"required":["address"]}}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Tested with `ajv`: https://runkit.com/embed/5qwkquyweir2

---

**OLD (not working):**

If you can allow `null` value to be equal to property not present, the schema could be that simple:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "age": {"type": "number"}
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "phone": {"type": "number"},
            "deletePhone": {"type": "null"}
          },
          "required": ["phone"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "phone": {"type": "null"},
            "deletePhone": {"type": "boolean"}
          },
          "required": ["deletePhone"]
        },
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "address": {"type": "string"},
            "deleteAddress": {"type": "null"}
          },
          "required": ["address"]
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "address": {"type": "null"},
            "deleteAddress": {"type": "boolean"}
          },
          "required": ["deleteAddress"]
        },
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But if you can not allow `{"deletePhone":null,"phone":123}` schema is more complicated and repeated:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {"type": "string"},
    "age": {"type": "number"}
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "name": {},
            "age": {},
            "address": {},
            "deleteAddress": {},
            "phone": {"type": "number"}
          },
          "required": ["phone"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "name": {},
            "age": {},
            "address": {},
            "deleteAddress": {},
            "deletePhone": {"type": "boolean"}
          },
          "required": ["deletePhone"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {}
      ]
    },
    {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "name": {},
            "age": {},
            "phone": {},
            "deletePhone": {},
            "address": {"type": "string"}
          },
          "required": ["address"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "name": {},
            "age": {},
            "phone": {},
            "deletePhone": {},
            "deleteAddress": {"type": "boolean"}
          },
          "required": ["deleteAddress"],
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        {}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your second solution validates false for `{"phone": 34}`, and the first one is also not working for your given example. As you are using {} in oneOf, wouldn't it match again any json causing it to fail for `{"phone": 34}`, as it would match two schema in oneOf.

Comment: Indeed my solution wasn't working properly, please try the schema in updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Below schema works with all cases but it is lengthy.

```
{
  "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
      {
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "properties": {
                  "phone": {
                    "type": "number"
                  },
                  "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "deleteAddress": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "phone"
                ],
                "not": {
                  "required": [
                    "deletePhone"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "deletePhone": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "deleteAddress": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "deletePhone"
                ],
                "not": {
                  "required": [
                    "phone"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "required": [
                      "phone",
                      "address",
                      "deleteAddress"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "required": [
                      "deletePhone",
                      "address",
                      "deleteAddress"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "properties": {
                  "address": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "phone": {
                    "type": "number"
                  },
                  "deletePhone": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "address"
                ],
                "not": {
                  "required": [
                    "deleteAddress"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "properties": {
                  "deleteAddress": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  },
                  "phone": {
                    "type": "number"
                  },
                  "deletePhone": {
                    "type": "boolean"
                  }
                },
                "required": [
                  "deleteAddress"
                ],
                "not": {
                  "required": [
                    "address"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "oneOf": [
                  {
                    "required": [
                      "address",
                      "phone",
                      "deletePhone"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "required": [
                      "deleteAddress",
                      "phone",
                      "deletePhone"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "properties": {
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "age": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
    ]
}
```