# json schema definition using conditional statements

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Iam trying to define an optional condition using json schema conditional statement (Using draft 7)

I have a json response like this.

```
[{
    "views": [{
            "name": "RSO Roster",
            "displayOrder": 5,
            "groups": [{
                    "type": "scrollable",
                    "displayOrder": 1,
                    "auditType": "player-pregame_roster",
                    "tiles": [{
                            "context": "event",
                            "dataStamp": 1535184247,
                            "tile_type": "person"
                        }, {
                            "context": "event",
                            "errorCode": 2, 
                            "errorText": "seloger",                                 
                            "tile_type": "person"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Leaders",
            "displayOrder": 1,
            "groups": [{
                    "type": "static",
                    "displayOrder": 1,                      
                    "tiles": [{
                            "context": "event",
                            "dataStamp": 1535184247,
                            "eventId":123
                            "tile_type": "static"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}]
```

In this response if the tile object contains the key `errorCode` the required field must  be `errorText` and `errorCode` keys.Like wise
if the tile object doessnot contains any "`errorCode`" or "`errorText`" key then the tile item contains the required field "`dataStamp`".

To validate the above condition i have defined a schema like below.But it is not working.Whats wrong with my schema .

```
 {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "views": {
                "$id": "views",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$id": "views/items",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "groups": {
                            "$id": "views/groups",
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$id": "views/groups/items",
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "tiles": {
                                        "$id": "views/groups/tiles",
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "$id": "views/groups/tiles/items",
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "dataStamp": {
                                                    "$id": "views/groups/tiles/dataStamp",
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "tile_type": {
                                                    "$id": "views/groups/tiles/tile_type",
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "errorCode": {
                                                    "type": "integer",
                                                    "enum": [
                                                        2, 10
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "errorText": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "enum": [
                                                        "seloger", "france24"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "if": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "tile_type": {
                                                        "enum": ["person"]
                                                    },
                                                    "errorCode": {
                                                        "enum": [2, 10]
                                                    }

                                                },
                                                "required": ["errorCode", "errorText"]
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "type",
                                    "tiles"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "groups"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "views"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement is missing `required` in `properties`:

```
                                        "if": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "tile_type": {
                                                    "enum": ["person"]
                                                },
                                                "errorCode": {
                                                    "enum": [2, 10]
                                                },
                                                "required": ["errorCode"]
                                            }
                                        },
```

If there is no `required` the value of property is validated only if the property is set. So original `if` schema would pass any object without `tile_type` and `errorCode`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51034071/329463 might give you some inspiration on building exclusive properties clusters.

EDIT: modified full schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "views": {
                "$id": "views",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$id": "views/items",
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "groups": {
                            "$id": "views/groups",
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$id": "views/groups/items",
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "tiles": {
                                        "$id": "views/groups/tiles",
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "$id": "views/groups/tiles/items",
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {                                                                                                                                             
                                                "dataStamp": {
                                                    "$id": "views/groups/tiles/dataStamp",
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },                                              
                                                "tile_type": {
                                                    "$id": "views/groups/tiles/tile_type",
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "errorCode": {
                                                    "type": "integer",
                                                    "enum": [
                                                        2, 10
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                "errorText": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "enum": [
                                                        "seloger", "france24"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "if": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "tile_type": {
                                                        "enum": ["person"]
                                                    },
                                                    "errorCode": {
                                                        "enum": [2, 10]
                                                    }

                                                },
                                                "required":["errorCode"]
                                            },
                                            "then": {
                                                "required": ["errorCode", "errorText"]
                                            },
                                            "else": {
                                                "required": ["dataStamp"]
                                            }

                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "required": [
                                    "type",
                                    "tiles"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "groups"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "views"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working.I have update the modified schema as you suggested.But schema is not showing error messages while changing the expected key values "errorCode" to "errorCode1" in the response

Comment: I have added full schema to my answer, it works for me at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: Thank you...But it is not working when the json response changes...(dynamic response) .I have updated the latest response in my question.....if the tile_type is static the above schema is not working...actually i dont want to validate tile_type static filed items.if the response doent contain static tile_type the above schema is working....How can i modify the schema compatible with static tile type as well.....

Comment: error am getting while using the above schema definition id :tile_type: static is not a valid enum value